# wrong stop statement declaration after define object

Tags: scala

I know this question is really simple but because i'm a new comer to Scala, I cannot figure out. Here is my sample code:

```
package datastructure

sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tails: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
    case Nil => 0
    case Cons(x, xs) => x + sum(xs)
  }

  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(x, xs) => x * product(xs)
  }
}

var a: Int = 3
```

I don't know I always meet follwing error at last line:

> wrong stop statement declaration

Here is a demonstration illustration: 
[image]

Comment: you can't declare a var outside of an object or class.

Comment: I'm working on scala worksheet. So scala still prevent me to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to declare a variable outside of a class or an object.

If you are working on a Scala worksheet get rid of the package declaration.

`package datastructure`